# Change all files from a specific folder extensions in AutoIT

Tags: scripting, autoit

I want to change the files extensions from `.txt` to `.pdf` in the folder `"D:/TestFolder"` using AutoIT what function can I use and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following function, you can do it flexible:

```
#include <File.au3>

_RenameFilesByExtInFolder('C:\YOUR_PATH', 'txt', 'log')

Func _RenameFilesByExtInFolder($sPathFolder, $sExtOld, $sExtNew, $fOverwrite=0)
    Local $iTrimLen = StringLen($sExtOld)
    Local $sPathNew
    Local $aFiles = _FileListToArray($sPathFolder, '*.' & $sExtOld, 1, True)
    If Not @error Then
        For $i = 1 To $aFiles[0]
            $sPathNew = StringFormat('%s%s', StringTrimRight($aFiles[$i], $iTrimLen), $sExtNew)
            If FileMove($aFiles[$i], $sPathNew, $fOverwrite) Then FileDelete($aFiles[$i])
        Next
    EndIf
EndFunc
```